# How to close a GLUT window with a Mac

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glut

I am trying to close an OpenGL's window in a program compile with g++-9 -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL in the Terminal of a MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 
I tried using glutDestroyWindow() but i get a warnign : 
  GLUT Warning: glutDestroyWindow attempted on bogus window 0

I have a cone that is rotating and implements its rotattion from an array of datas. I would want the animation to stop as soon as the array finishes its elements.

```
  void idleCone(void)
{
    for(int j = 1; j<10000 ; j++){
        double i = dati[j+1][0];

        int win = glutGetWindow();
        if(i == 0.) {     glutDestroyWindow(win);
        }
        xRotated = 180/M_PI*(dati[j][0]);
        yRotated = 180/M_PI*(dati[j][1]);
        zRotated = 180/M_PI*(dati[j][2]);

        displayCone();
        xRotated += 0.;
        yRotated += 0.;
        zRotated += 0.;
        displayCone();

    }}
```

where dati is :

```
   std::vector<std::array<GLfloat, 3>> &dati
```

In main I have

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
                xRotated = yRotated = zRotated = 0.0;
                xRotated=0.0;
                yRotated=0.0;
                glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);


                glutDisplayFunc(displayCone);
                glutReshapeFunc(reshapeCone);
                glutIdleFunc(idleCone);

                glutMainLoop();
```

where this is displayCone function

```
void displayCone(void){

    // clear the drawing buffer.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  //

    // set matrix mode
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    // clear model view matrix
    glLoadIdentity();
    // multiply view matrix to current matrix
    gluLookAt(3.0, 3.0, 3.0-4.5, 0.0, 0.0,-4.5,0,1,0);

    // ******
    glPushMatrix();


    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -4.5);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(2.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 2.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 2.0);
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();

    // clear the drawing buffer.
    // glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  // <---- delete

    // traslate the draw by z = -4.0
    // Note this when you decrease z like -8.0 the drawing will looks far , or smaller.
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-4.5);
    // Red color used to draw.
    glColor3f(0.8, 0.2, 0.1);
    // changing in transformation matrix.
    // rotation about X axis
    glRotatef(xRotated,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    // rotation about Y axis
    glRotatef(yRotated,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    // rotation about Z axis
    glRotatef(zRotated,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    // scaling transfomation
    glScalef(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    // built-in (glut library) function , draw you a Cone.

    // move the peak of the cone to the origin
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -height);

    glutSolidCone(base,height,slices,stacks);
    // Flush buffers to screen
    // gluLookAt(3,3,3,0,0,-4.5,0,1,0); <----------------------- delete

    glFlush();
    // sawp buffers called because we are using double buffering
    // glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

I also tried to use

```
exit(0)
```

but I would want the program to keep going after the animation. 
I know that i should use something such as glutLeaveMainLoop() but i am still not able to do it since my Mac says

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glutLeaveMainLoop", referenced from:
      idleCone()    in ccnOmxBT.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

even if i included freeglut.h . Is there any way to compile from terminal including freeglut.h or closing the window successfully ?

Comment: How did you create the window? Is it possible there are multiple entries in `dati` where `i==0`?

Comment: @Botje the Problem is that when i == 0 the window isn't destroyed

Comment: ... because `glutGetWindow` returned 0. Which is why I asked how you created the window in the first place.

Comment: In short: please show more code. This snippet is not enough to identify the problem or even try to reproduce it.

Comment: okay @Botje, done it

Comment: A quick search shows that GLUT does not have a way of exiting the main loop, and FreeGLUT requires an X server on macOS. I would strongly advise a third option: dropping GLUT altogether and switching to [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html). It is a much more modern library and gives you just enough control. The callbacks you have now should fit in the GLFW loop just fine.